# передача массива в функцию на питоне

Tags: python, массивы, функции, return

Как на питоне передать массив на выход в функцию? Делаю минимализацию по методу квайна, там очень полезно будет это использование.

Comment: Так же, как аргумент любого другого типа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Под массивом вы скорее всего имеете в виду list? Не совсем понятно в чем проблема его передачи в функцию:

```
def my_function(some_list):
    #code
    pass

my_function([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Или предварительно записав его в переменную

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_function(my_list)
```

Comment: invalid syntax же!

Comment: @andreymal где? почему?

Comment: Вы сами-то пробовали первый пример запустить?

Comment: @andreymal, а, все, тупанул, сейчас поправлю)

Comment: Да и второй пример тоже просто не работает, потому что локальная переменная my_list перекроет глобальную, и глобальный список будет недоступен внутри функции

Comment: @andreymal поправил еще раз)